# File synchronization on Linux over network: scp or rsync?

Tags: linux, sync, rsync, scp

I have two Linux (Debian) machines "A"  and "B"  connected to each other wireless over the router.

On the machine "A"  I run a script that generates every 5 seconds a new 1MB file  in the specific folder (e.g.  ~/files/). Files do not change after generation.

After the file is generated, it should be available on the machine "B" together with other files, that were generated previously.

What is the most efficient way (according to the CPU / network usage and transfer time), to do it?

Suggestions:

- run `scp` in the script to copy the file after it was  generated, so every file is copied individually.
- run `rsync` to synchronize the folder contents between the machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rsync`. SCP has a bigger overhead.

Also think of sharing connections using `ControlMaster`. If you would transfer this only file every 5 seconds, most of the time you would spend initiating connection, instead of transferring files.

Answer (score 2):

Use Rsync,

Rsyc only copies files that have changed since the last copy and saves lots of bandwidth and CPU.

SCP is very tricky to only copy changed files, and per default copies the full folder each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a shared folder between those two machines with, say, `NFS` or another sharing protocol.